# How do I solve a 2nd order differential equation for projectile motion with air resistance?

Tags: python, math, physics, numerical-methods, differential-equations

the equation is:

```
d^2 r/dt^2 = -c/m (dr/dt)+g
```

where r is the position of the projectile, c is the drag coefficient, m is the mass of the projectile and g is the acceleration due to gravity.

Assuming only two-dimensions in component form this, of course, reads,

```
d^2 X/dt^2 = -c(dX/dt)= U
d^2 Y/dt^2 = -c/m(dY/dt)+g
```

if we employ the methodology described above and define explicitly the velocities in X AND Y as,

```
U = dX/dt
```

and

```
V = dX/dt
```

then the entire coupled system of equations is,

```
dU/dt= -c/m(U)
dV/dt= - c/m(V)+g
dX/dt= U
dY/dt = V
```

The parameters for this system of ODEs are c = 0.5 kgs^−1, m = 2kg and g = −9.81 ms^−2.

initialising the variables as `(U0, V0, X0, Y0) = (173, 100, 0, 0)` which launches the projectile from the origin at an angle of ∼ 30 degrees from the horizontal.

how to I write a new function in python using rk4 (I want to know how to code this) that implements the system of four ODEs above that solve the 2D projectile motion problem....? please help I am very new to ODEs AND CODING. THANKS

---

I have got the following so far...and its not working  and I really don't know what to do for this specific problem, I am meant to obtain a projectile graph as well...can someone please improve my code pls thanks

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def projectileMotion_V(t, M, g, c):
   return -c/M * V0 + g 


def projectileMotion_U(t, c, M):
   return -c/M * U0

V0 = 100         
U0 = 173
ang = 30.0      
c = 0.5       
dt = 0.1  
M = 2.0         
g = -9.81 
h = 0.1

t = [0]                         
x = [0]                         
y = [0]
vx = [V0*np.cos((ang*np.pi)/180)]  
vy = [U0*np.sin((ang*np.pi)/180)]
ax = [-(c*V0*np.cos((ang*np.pi)/180))/M]          
ay = [g-(c*U0*np.sin((ang*np.pi)/180))/M]



def solveODEsWithR4Method(t, x, y, vx, vy, ax, ay):
   t.append(t[0]+dt)                
   vx.append(vx[0]+dt*ax[0])  
   vy.append(vy[0]+dt*ay[0])
   x.append(x[0]+dt*vx[0])    
   y.append(y[0]+dt*vy[0])    
   vel = np.sqrt(vx[0+1]**2 + vy[0+1]**2)   
   drag = c*vel                                    
   ax.append(-(drag*np.cos(ang/180*np.pi))/M)     
   ay.append(-g-(drag*np.sin(ang/180*np.pi)/M)) 
return -c/M * V0 + g 


fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(t, M, g, c)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi there, and welcome- What has your 'net search turned up?  For example, I see: https://www.codeproject.com/tips/792927/fourth-order-runge-kutta-method-in-python , and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IOkwWYaZbck  There are two things here, coding, and solve the ODEs.  You might want to start with coding something simple, like the solution to the quadratic equation, and then a simple 1D ODE, to get your 'python legs', and then tackle this problem.

Comment: Air resistance is quadratic in the speed, you are using water resistance (but with the wrong coefficient), see https://stackoverflow.com/a/35009733/3088138 for how that computation should look like.

Comment: This is an  inhomogeneous system of linear differential equations with constant coefficients. You can solve it completely and obtain the exact solutions, so there is no need for numerical integration.

Answer (score 3):

As nothing else happens in these times of a pandemic of delusions about phantasmic killer viruses...

Please do not call it [air resistance, that is specifically `k*|v|*v`](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2748481/115115). As for this to be a force the coefficient `k` would need to have units `kg/m`, which is not what you are given, your formulas for the resistance are probably correct. Call it "medium resistance" instead, water resistance would behave that way.

Then code the acceleration

```py
c = 0.5; m = 2; g = -9.81;
def motion(x,v):
    x,y,vx,vy = v
    return np.array([vx,vy, -c/m * vx + g, -c/m * vy ])
```

Copy the RK4 code from [somewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53650879/3088138) that is geared towards vector states

```
def RK4step(f,u,dt):
    k1 = dt*f(u)
    k2 = dt*f(u+0.5*k1)
    k3 = dt*f(u+0.5*k2)
    k4 = dt*f(u+k3)
    return u + (k1+2*k2+2*k3+k4)/6

def RK4integrate(f, u0, tspan):
    u = np.zeros([len(tspan),len(u0)])
    u[0,:]=u0
    for k in range(1, len(tspan)):
        u[k,:] = RK4step(f, u[k-1], tspan[k]-tspan[k-1])
    return u
```

and apply both codes together to compute a trajectory

```
dt = .1
t = np.arange(0,10,dt)
u0 = np.array([0, 0, 173, 100])

sol_RK4 = RK4integrate(motion, u0, t)
x,y,vx,vy = sol_RK4.T
plt.plot(x,y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `v = dr/dt`. Then the equations become:

```matlab
dv/dt = - (c/m) * v  +  g
```

Multiply both sides of the equation with `exp((c/m)*t)`:

```matlab
exp((c/m)*t) * dv/dt = - exp((c/m)*t) * (c/m) * v  +  exp((c/m)*t) * g
```

Move the first column of terms from the right-hand side to the left one:

```matlab
exp((c/m)*t) * dv/dt + exp((c/m)*t) * (c/m) * v  =  exp((c/m)*t) * g
```

Then by the product rule of differentiation, applied to `exp((c/m)*t) * v`, one gets

```matlab
d/dt( exp((c/m)*t) * v )  =  exp((c/m)*t) * g

d/dt( exp((c/m)*t) * v )  =  d/dt( (m/c) * exp((c/m)*t) * g )
```

Now you can integrate both sides with respect to `t` and there exists a vector `u0` such that

```matlab
exp((c/m)*t) * v  =  u0  +  (m/c) * exp((c/m)*t) * g
```

Multiply both sides by `exp(-(c/m)*t)`:

```matlab
v  =  exp(-(c/m)*t) * u0  +  (m/c) * g
```

If the initial velocity is v0, then you have to set `u0 = v0 - (m/c)*g` so the final formula for the velocity is:

```matlab
v  =  exp(-(c/m)*t) * ( v0 - (m/c)*g )  +  (m/c) * g
```

Integrate `v` one more time with respect to `t` and you get the formula for the position:

```matlab
r  = r0 - (m/c) * ( v0 + (m/c)*g )  - (m/c) * exp(-(c/m)*t) * ( v0 - (m/c)*g )  +  (m/c) * t * g
```

where `r0` is the initial position.

So the final formulas for the solution are

```matlab
r  = r0 - v0 + (m/c)*g  +  exp(-(c/m)*t) * ( v0 - (m/c)*g )  +  (m/c) * t * g

v  =  exp(-(c/m)*t) * ( v0 - (m/c)*g )  +  (m/c) * g
```